# Creating "performance" output bars in iOS - Photoshop/programming interplay

Tags: ios

My partner and I are trying to figure out how best to create scaling, colored performance bars for one of our mobile exam-prep apps. The goal is to create a horizontal bar that graphically represents a scale of 0 - 100% using Photoshop or something similar. We had hired a professional graphics designer but we're left holding the bag trying to figure out how to make the graphics actually "fill the bar" in the actual app.

(I can't post pictures yet, but you can see a link to the picture here):
http://www.productionplanningpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Screen-Shot-2012-06-25-at-9.47.24-PM.png

As the bar would reach certain percentages, it would change color from Red to Green appropriately. I'm trying to figure out how to give this to my contractor without handing him 100 files, each showing 1% more of the bar (and even then, I'm not a graphics artist, so this whole thing is above my head). I've done as much research as I can stand, and I've seen the fancy iOS graphing APIs - we're just looking to fill in these two bars.

Any insight or help is SUPER appreciated!! Thanks!
Jotuned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few solutions to this problem.  I'm sure there's a way to fill in the area with that shadow programmatically, and I'm also sure someone will come along with a masking solution sooner or later.

The quickest and easiest way, though, is to have your artist simply create that red filler bar one time, and have it fill the entire space (ie. drawn at 100%).  Then you make sure that, in the graphic that is the 'outside' of the bar, the space where the red bar should be is an alpha channel.

When you actually get to coding it, place the red bar at the very bottom of all the objects you're drawing to the screen.  The rest of your UI should entirely hide it.  Then as progress moves from 0% to 100%, you move the bar slowly to the right, filling in the space (and showing through the alpha hole in the 'bar holder'.

Quick, simple, have done this many times before.  Masking would work as well, but seems a bit overkill in your situation (and I don't have any experience with it on iOS, so I can't offer any assistance there!)  Let me know if you have any questions while trying to implement this :)

Comment: No problem--glad I could help! : D